# Printing Minimum Sum Path of a Tree

Tags: java, tree

I have a code that calculates the minimum sum path of a tree that I have created.

My Tree Class is like this:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
public class SolutionTree {

    SolutionNode root;

    public SolutionTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public void addRoot(int rootValue) {
        root = new SolutionNode(rootValue);
    }

    // New Node Adder
    public void addSolutionNode(int newNodeValue) {
        SolutionNode newNode = new SolutionNode(newNodeValue);
        SolutionNode newNodeRoot = breadth(root);
        if(newNodeRoot.getChildLeft() == null) {
            newNodeRoot.setChildLeft(newNode);
            newNode.setParentLeft(newNodeRoot);
        }
        else if(newNodeRoot.getChildRight() == null) {
            newNodeRoot.setChildRight(newNode);
            newNode.setParentLeft(newNodeRoot);
            if(newNodeRoot != root) {
                    if(newNodeRoot.getParentLeft().getChildRight().getChildLeft() == null) {
                        newNodeRoot.getParentLeft().getChildRight().setChildLeft(newNode);
                        newNode.setParentRight(newNodeRoot.getParentLeft().getChildRight());
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    // Node Class of Solution Tree
    protected class SolutionNode {

        private int value;
        private SolutionNode parentLeft;
        private SolutionNode parentRight;
        private SolutionNode childLeft;
        private SolutionNode childRight;

        // Constructor
        public SolutionNode() {
            value = 0;
            parentLeft = null;
            parentRight = null;
            childLeft = null;
            childRight = null;
        }

        // Constructor
        public SolutionNode(int v) {
            value = v;
            parentLeft = null;
            parentRight = null;
            childLeft = null;
            childRight = null;
        }

        // MODIFIERS

        public void setValue(int val) {
            value = val;
        }

        public void setParentLeft(SolutionNode leftParent) {
            parentLeft = leftParent;
        }

    public void setParentRight(SolutionNode rightParent) {
        parentLeft = rightParent;
    }

        public void setChildLeft(SolutionNode leftChild) {
            childLeft = leftChild;
        }

        public void setChildRight(SolutionNode rightChild) {
            childRight = rightChild;
        }

        //ACCESSORS

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public SolutionNode getParentLeft() {
            return parentLeft;
        }

        public SolutionNode getParentRight() {
            return parentRight;
        }

        public SolutionNode getChildLeft() {
            return childLeft;
        }

        public SolutionNode getChildRight() {
            return childRight;
        }




    }

    // function to compute the minimum sum path
    // It only returns the sum of the values of nodes on the min sum path 
    int minSumPath(SolutionNode current) {
        if(current == null)
            return 0;

        int sum = current.getValue();

        int left_sum = minSumPath(current.childLeft);
        int right_sum = minSumPath(current.childRight);

        if(left_sum <= right_sum) {
            sum += minSumPath(current.childLeft);
        }
        else {
            sum += minSumPath(current.childRight);
        }

        return sum;
    }

    // Breadth First Traversal
    public static SolutionNode breadth(SolutionNode root) {
        Queue<SolutionNode> queue = new LinkedList<SolutionNode>() ;
        if (root == null)
            return null;
        queue.clear();
        queue.add(root);
       while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            SolutionNode node = queue.remove();
            if(node.childLeft != null) 
                queue.add(node.childLeft);
            if(node.childRight != null) 
                queue.add(node.childRight);
            if(node.childLeft == null || node.childRight == null)
                return node;
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

I have a program that reads integers from a .txt file and adds to the Solution Tree and calculates the minimum sum path of the tree (from the root to the leaf nodes(summation of the valeus of nodes)). By calling minSumPath method of SolutionTree.

I want to print the calculated path. Like for excample if the tree is:

```
        1
    2        3
4        5        6
```

The minimum sum path is 7 and it is calculated by summing 1 + 2 + 4. I want to print this process. Any ideas how can I do this? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning an int in the recursive method you should return a class that holds the sum and the String of the nodes you have passed.

This code should work for you:

```
 public class number{
    private int sum;
    private String str;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public number(int sum, String str){
        this.sum=sum;
        this.str=str;
    }

    public void add(int sum2){
        sum+=sum2;
        if(!str.equals(""))
            str = str +" + "+ sum2;
        else if(str.equals(""))
            str = "" + sum2;
    }

    // ACCESSORS
    public String getStr() {
        return this.str;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return this.sum;
    }

    // MODIFIERS
    public void setStr(String newStr) {
        this.str = newStr;
    }

    public void setSum(int newSum) {
        this.sum = newSum;
    }

}
// function to compute the minimum sum path
// It only returns the sum of the values of nodes on the min sum path 
number minSumPath(SolutionNode current) {
  number  tr1= new number(0,"");
    if(current == null){
        return tr1;
    }
    int sum = current.getValue();

    int left_sum = minSumPath(current.childLeft).sum;
    int right_sum = minSumPath(current.childRight).sum;

    if(left_sum <= right_sum) {
       tr1= minSumPath(current.childLeft);
        tr1.add(sum);
    }
    else {
        tr1= minSumPath(current.childLeft);
        tr1.add(sum);
       }
    return tr1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly tough I did changed a bit at my main program but nevermind thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you creaete a BalancedSearchTree instead, the minimum sum will always be towards the left and if that fails, towards the right, then all you would have to do is iterate through the tree until you hit the end. This way you won't have to visit all the nodes on the tree.

Something like this:

```
private int minPath(Node<E> n, int min, ArrayList<Integer> pathTaken) {
    if (n.left != null) {// Left is smaller than parent and exists, go there
        pathTaken.add(n.value);
        return minPath(n.left, min + n.value);
    }
    else if (n.right != null) {// Else go right
        pathTaken.add(n.value);
        return minPath(n.right, min + n.value);
    }
    return min; // There are no more children 
}

public minSumPath() {
    if (root == null)
        return -1;
    ArrayList<Integer> pathTaken = new ArrayList<>();
    pathTaken.add(root.getValue());
    int min = minSumPath(root, pathTaken);
    System.out.println("Patk taken: " + pathTaken.toString());
    return min;
}
```

To keep a record of the taken path, you simply add an ArrayList to your recursive methods argument. Note that I didn't check if the added path was null, which you probably should.

```
private int minSumPath(SolutionNode current, ArrayList<Integer> pathTaken) {
        if(current == null)
            return 0;

        int sum = current.getValue();

        int left_sum = minSumPath(current.childLeft);
        int right_sum = minSumPath(current.childRight);

        if(left_sum <= right_sum) {
            pathTaken.add(current.childLeft.getValue());
            sum += minSumPath(current.childLeft);
        }
        else {
            pathTaken.add(current.childRight.getValue());
            sum += minSumPath(current.childRight);
        }

        return sum;
    }

public minSumPath() {
    if (root == null)
        return -1;
    ArrayList<Integer> pathTaken = new ArrayList<>();
    pathTaken.add(root.getValue());
    int min = minSumPath(root, pathTaken);
    System.out.println("Patk taken: " + pathTaken.toString());
    return min;
}
```

A optimization that you could do is to store a variable of the latest minimum path found and whenever the path it's on is greater than the previous record you return Integer.MAX_VALUE and abort the recurssion of that branch as it won't find a shorter path there.